# An error occurred while packaging. Using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to build a python file into a exe file. I don't get it since it builds on some days and gives errors on others. The python script works normally when I run it in CMD or Visual Code.

I have tried :

- Reinstalling Django
- Reinstalling Python
- Reinstalling auto-py-to-exe
- Installing GDAL
- Running CMD as Admin

Error that comes up when trying to build the exe :

````
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.10.1
Building directory: C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "C:/Users/white/Desktop/Security/password.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console C:/Users/white/Desktop/Security/password.py --distpath C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz\application --workpath C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz\build --specpath C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz

4527 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
4542 INFO: Python: 3.9.7
4563 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
4573 INFO: wrote C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz\password.spec
4576 INFO: UPX is not available.
4590 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\white\\Desktop\\Security',
 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmphwzenqcz']
4794 INFO: checking Analysis
4796 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
4812 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
4830 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
4853 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6467 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
6475 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib'
8715 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
8863 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
8876 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
8926 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll
8934 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\white\Desktop\Security\password.py
9313 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
15327 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
15330 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
25292 INFO: Processing module hooks...
25311 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25329 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-Crypto.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25347 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25523 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-eel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25616 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lz4.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25631 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
25633 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25637 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25646 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25664 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.core.cache.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25770 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.core.mail.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
25807 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.core.management.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26521 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'matplotlib'
26529 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.db.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
27015 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.__pycache__.base" not found!
27020 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
30750 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
37528 INFO: Packages required by django:
['sqlparse', 'tzdata', 'asgiref']
41420 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.template.loaders.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
41497 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
41553 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwzenqcz\password.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['C:/Users/white/Desktop/Security/password.py'],
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 473, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 373, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 451, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 408, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 632, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 529, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1029, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 854, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 274, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-gevent.py", line 16, in <module>
    datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 1156, in collect_all
    hiddenimports = collect_submodules(package_name,
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 597, in collect_submodules
    names = exec_statement("""
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 98, in exec_statement
    return __exec_statement(statement, capture_stdout=True)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 79, in __exec_statement
    return __exec_python_cmd(cmd, capture_stdout=capture_stdout)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 70, in __exec_python_cmd
    txt = compat.exec_python(*cmd, env=pp_env)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 565, in exec_python
    return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 332, in exec_command
    out = proc.communicate(timeout=60)[0]
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1134, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1510, in _communicate
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, orig_timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '('C:\\Users\\white\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe', '-c', '\nimport sys\nimport pkgutil\nimport traceback\n\n# ``pkgutil.walk_packages`` doesn\'t walk subpackages of zipped files\n# per https://bugs.python.org/issue14209. This is a workaround.\ndef walk_packages(path=None, prefix=\'\', onerror=None):\n    def seen(p, m={}):\n        if p in m:\n            return True\n        m[p] = True\n\n    for importer, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(path, prefix):\n        if not name.startswith(prefix):   ## Added\n            name = prefix + name          ## Added\n        yield importer, name, ispkg\n\n        if ispkg:\n            try:\n                __import__(name)\n            except ImportError:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n            except Exception:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n                else:\n                    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)\n                    print("collect_submodules: failed to import %r!" %\n                          name, file=sys.stderr)\n            else:\n                path = getattr(sys.modules[name], \'__path__\', None) or []\n\n                # don\'t traverse path items we\'ve seen before\n                path = [p for p in path if not seen(p)]\n\n                ## Use Py2 code here. It still works in Py3.\n                for item in walk_packages(path, name+\'.\', onerror):\n                    yield item\n                ## This is the original Py3 code.\n                #yield from walk_packages(path, name+\'.\', onerror)\n\nfor module_loader, name, ispkg in walk_packages([\'C:\\\\Users\\\\white\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python39\\\\lib\\\\site-packages\\\\gevent\'], \'gevent.\'):\n    print(\'\\n$_pyi:\' + name + \'*\')\n')' timed out after 60 seconds

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out! The issue was Windows Defender blocking the file when it was created.